# Why my C++ templated function does not produce `undeclared identified` compile error?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create an abstraction about Lights (I'm building a game in C++) and I'm using templates to do that. A part of my code right now is:

```
// Light.hpp
template <typename LightType>
void LoadLight(GLuint shaderId, const LightType& light, const std::string& glslUniformName)
{
    // Load common light attributes
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader.GetProgID(), (glslUniformName + ".ambient").c_str()),  light.ambient.x,  light.ambient.y,  light.ambient.z);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader.GetProgID(), (glslUniformName + ".diffuse").c_str()),  light.diffuse.x,  light.diffuse.y,  light.diffuse.z);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader.GetProgID(), (glslUniformName + ".specular").c_str()), light.specular.x, light.specular.y, light.specular.z);

    // Load specific light attributes
    LoadLightSpecific<LightType>(shaderId, light, glslUniformName); // ???
}

template <typename LightType>
void LoadLightSpecific(GLuint shaderId, const LightType& light, const std::string& glslUniformName);
```

The specializations for `LoadLightSpecific` is on a separate `.cpp` file which is irrelevant with my question.

My problem is in the line with the `???`.
I am using `LoadLightSpecific` before I define it! I thought that this would give me a `undeclared identifier` (or something like that) compile error but no. It works normally.

Why is that happening? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

**Update 23/11/2015**

So, as people recommended in comments I used Wandbox to recreate the problem with minimal code. I ended up [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bXlDn2sjwC8360qw). Apparently, the answer to my question seems to be:

"The code **should** not compile but somehow MSVC works his way around the problem"

Comment: LoadLight's body is compiled only when instantiated, and it's very possible that LoadLightSpecific is defined when LoadLight is instantiated.

Comment: Try to just run the preprocessor and check it for yourself.

Comment: @akappa Hmm.. I'm using `LoadLight` first time in my `Main.cpp` where I `#include "Light.hpp"`. So you're saying that maybe that's the reason `LoadLight`'s body can actually "see" `LoadLightSpecific` ? I suppose it makes sense!

Comment: Yup. Compiler defer parsing template bodies until they are instantiated.

Comment: @akappa not all of them do. MSVC does, but GCC (at least older versions) does not.

Comment: I admit I didn't check what I said on the standard, but it seems kind of obvious that, *in general*, you can't really parse a template body before instantiation: otherwise, how can you tell if a "(say) "`using V = typename T::Blah`", where `T` is a template parameter, is valid or not?

Comment: Definitely sounds like MSVC; that line won't parse correctly without knowing that `LoadLightSpecific` is a *template-name*.

Comment: You should post an MCVE so people can try this on standards compliant compilers.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The compiler is MSVC

Comment: @juanchopanza What is an "MCVE" ?

Comment: There are these web applications you can use to look stuff up. Typically all you need to do is type a term into them and they give you back a list of pages featuring that term.

Comment: Well @juanchopanza is basically saying is that we need a code sample that someone can use to reproduce the problem you are seeing but is not too large. As far as I can tell your code same is not valid C++. MSVC is known not to handle two-phase look-up correctly. We could provide an answer that is most likely correct but it would just be a guess since we don't have enough code.

Comment: This is also where sites like [wanbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) and [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) come in handy as well. Unfortunately [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) does not allow live links.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I used wandbox and updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

It is not unusual with templates that when writing them, you *assume* something about the template arguments. i.e:

```
Template<class T>
class C
{ 
    void foo() { T.bar(); }
};
```

Even though we dont know if `T` will actually have a method `bar()`, the compiler accepts it at the moment, because it is just a "template", not actual code. At the time when you *instantiate* a template, with some arguments, the compiler will check for the correctness of what you assumed, because now it has to generate code.

In the case of functions it is the same. **The same logic must apply unless somebody finds an explicit statement about it in the standard**, which I tried to find and didn't.

If we follow this logic, when you wrote the template of `LoadLight`, you *assumed* that there exists such a function called `LoadLightSpecific<T>`. In other words,

**Why would `T.bar()` and `bar<T>()` be accepted in a class template, but not in a function template?**

The templated function is not translated at the place of its templated definition, but when it is actually called (similar to the *instantiation* of a templated class) with some specific template argument. If at that place, all what is needed is available (`LoadLightSpecific` declared), then it will work fine.

However, I think that it is good practice to, as much as possible, have things declared at the place of the template definition. This will make it easier to track the dependencies.

Comment: Yeah that seems to make sense. I wasn't thinking that way. You're right. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I un-accepted your answer because I no longer think it is 100% correct. Based on what you say my code is fine. Apparently (I updated my question) it is not. Other compilers (GCC for instance) complain about it.

Comment: @TheCrafter, the question is not whether it is MSVC or GCC who is right, that is the last of our concern! We are about the *logic* of C++ templates. Unless we find something in the Standard that resolves it explicitly, which we failed to find so far, we have to appeal to logic and common-sense. For instance, the class template accepts perfectly undefined symbols, until the moment of instantiation. I dont see why this rule should not apply to templated functions. Templated classes are the basis by the way, templated functions are just an extension to the concept!!

Comment: Yeah I agree. But if I accept it as a correct answer that means that the problem is solved and the question has an answer. Which is not true in our case. Your answer seems logical but my code will not work on gcc. Only on msvc. That's some new information right there that make the question more complex! I didn't mean to insult you if that's what I did.

Comment: Dont worry, I did not take it for an insult, lol. But I am defending my answer. Some fellows probably see the question as which compiler is right, and will tend to defend the one they use. To me the answer is crystal clear, the logic that applies to class templates should apply to function templates, **unless** someone finds an explicit statement about it in the standard. I tried to find such stuff in the standard but failed to. Hence my conclusion and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular code:

If there's a function template called `LoadLightSpecific` in scope at the point of definition, then this template definition is valid by itself. (It doesn't have to have that signature; even `template<int> void LoadLightSpecific();` will do.)

The reason for this is that the compiler must know `LoadLightSpecific` is a template in order to parse the `<` as the start of a template argument list, rather than the less-than operator.

Since `LoadLightSpecific<LightType>`, if parsed as a *template-id*, is dependent on a template parameter, name lookup for `LoadLightSpecific` is postponed until instantiation. (Note that this does not mean instantiation will necessarily succeed: a declaration that is not in the template definition context can only be found in the instantiation context by ADL, not by normal unqualified lookup.)

---

In the more general case, the standard [specifies](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res) what names are considered dependent on a template parameter and what aren't. Non-dependent names are looked up and bound at the point of template definition:

> If a name does not depend on a *template-parameter* (as defined in
>   14.6.2), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template
>   definition; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations)
>   found at that point and this binding is not affected by declarations
>   that are visible at the point of instantiation.

---

MSVC is well-known for its nonconformance in this area.